# Unshorten URL for Invalid / expired Hostnames?

Tags: python, url, python-requests

I used the following code snippet to unshorten URLs using the requests library. The snippet runs correctly for URL redirects of hostnames that are valid , and running webpages. But , this code and every other variants of the snippets of unshortening urls seem to fail when the final URL is invalid website.  I would still like to get what the final web page url is , regardless of being it an invalid one. 
The snippet is :

```
def unshorten_url(url):
    return requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True).url

print unshorten_url(<shortened URL>)
```

The shortened URL should redirect to this webpage, which has invalid host . 
http://trekingear.com/product/4-get-a-real-rocky-mountain-high/?utm_source=Content&utm_medium=Postings&utm_campaign=Guffey%20X%20Mass

But it returns me this error :

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='trekingear.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /product/4-get-a-real-rocky-mountain-high/?utm_source=Content&utm_medium=Postings&utm_campaign=Guffey%20X%20Mass (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10556dc50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))
```

Here is the URL I am trying to unshorten : 
[image]
How can I extract the final URL, of this invalid host from this redirection chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `requests.head` like that, since by default it follows a 302 Redirect up to three times.

You could disable redirection (with `retries=False`) and use `urlopen`. Then the returned response would always hold the 302 contents as its url:

> ```
> urlopen(method, url, body=None, headers=None, retries=None,
> redirect=True, assert_same_host=True, timeout=<object object>,
> pool_timeout=None, release_conn=None, chunked=False, body_pos=None,
> **response_kw)
> ```
>
> Get a connection from the pool and perform an HTTP request. This is the lowest level call for making a request, so you’ll need to specify all the raw details.
>
> ```
> Parameters:   
>
>     method – HTTP request method (such as GET, POST, PUT, etc.)
>     body – Data to send in the request body (useful for creating POST requests, see HTTPConnectionPool.post_url for more convenience).
>     headers – Dictionary of custom headers to send, such as User-Agent, If-None-Match, etc. If None, pool headers are used. If provided, these headers completely replace any pool-specific headers.
>     retries (Retry, False, or an int.) –
>
>     Configure the number of retries to allow before raising a MaxRetryError exception.
>
>     Pass None to retry until you receive a response. Pass a Retry object for fine-grained control over different types of retries. Pass an integer number to retry connection errors that many times, but no other types of errors. Pass zero to never retry.
> ```

And this is the relevant note:

> If `False`, then retries are disabled and any exception is raised immediately. Also, instead of raising a `MaxRetryError` on redirects, the redirect response will be returned.

## Example

(I have actually ran a different test on my local web server, but can't find a public one supplying *wrong* 302 requests).

```
from urllib3 import PoolManager

manager = PoolManager(10)

req = manager.urlopen("GET", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_E._Shannon", retries=False)

print req.get_redirect_location()
```

The above will request a HTTP page from Wikipedia, thus generating the redirect to HTTPS:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_E._Shannon
```

## Redirects *plus* no retries

Your case is a bit different. You want to do redirects since the original URL will not yield the real redirection on the first try, but you want to get the failed redirect.

The problem here is that **redirects are handled by the same code as error retries**, so you can't disable only the latter. It's neither or both.

You then have to enable both, and do it the long way (intercepting the error). *You might need to increase retries, which will slow down things when errors occur*.

```
try:
    // Did not know you can't post a URL shortener in a SO answer. Live and learn.
    req = manager.urlopen("GET", "http(COLON)(SLASH)(SLASH)t(DOT)co(SLASH)eWWk8s8Hzj")
    loc = req.get_redirect_location()
except MaxRetryError as fail:
    // build "loc" from scheme, host and url
    loc = "%s://%s%s" % (fail.pool.scheme, fail.pool.host, fail.url)

print loc
```

## Your specific case

Since you're using a urllib3 wrapper, you can just unwrap the exception:

```
try:
    # This is your existing code
    return requests.head(url, allow_redirects = True).url
except requests.ConnectionError as fail:
    return "%s://%s%s" % (fail.args[0].pool.scheme, fail.args[0].pool.host, fail.args[0].url)
```

You ought to provide for other possible errors, though.

Comment: I tried setting allow_redirects to False, it doesn't throw the error, but doesn't give me the desired final URL either.  If the host is invalid, I would like to extract the final URL  the shortener stopped at . Setting redirect to False , only avoided the error , which wouldn't help my case

Comment: I may have misunderstood. I have added a test example. Is this what you were looking for? This gives no error in case of a wrong 302 redirect, it just returns where it wants you to be redirected.

Comment: I have updated my post with the image showing URLI want to unshorten. I  tried your snippet on it, It just returns me the original shortened URL, rather than the unshortened one.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It returns the same url **with https protocol**, which redirects to `http://dld.bz/dysBG`, which finally redirects to the URL you want. So, you need to follow the redirects until you get an error. Amending answer

Comment: I have handled the cases for the clean redirections ( not like the upper one ) differently, as expected. Your snippet worked for the failed hostname ones. Thank you!